# Select table from database with radio buttons

Tags: php, pdo, radio-button

I need to select a table from the database based on the radio button that has been selected. The way I thought this would work is, 1) by determining what radio-button has been selected in an if-statement and assigning it a variable; and, 2) assigning that variable to the $dbname (variable for the table) that is being used in the PDO to connect. I haven't been successful in my attempts, so I need to know how to take the variable from the if-statement and use it in PDO (or be told of a better solution).

Example html (there are three radio buttons):

```
<div id="radio_buttons">
                    <label for="p_book">Book</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_radio" id="p_book" value="p_book">

                    <label for="p_article">Article</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_radio" id="p_article" value="p_article">

                    <label for="journal">Journal</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_radio" id="p_journal" value="p_journal">


                </div> <!-- end radiobuttons -->
```

How I target the radio buttons in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['edify_button'])) {

        if(isset($_POST['p_radio'])) {
            $radio_values = $_POST['p_radio'];
            if ($radio_values == 'p_book') {
                $dbname = 'books'; //this is the name of the table
                return $dbname;

            }elseif ($radio_values == 'p_article') {
                $dbname = 'articles';
                return $dbname;


            }elseif ($radio_values == 'p_journal') {
                $dbname = 'journals';
                return $dbname;

            }
        }else{
                echo 'unchecked';
    }
    }
```

And then I want to, somehow, get that variable to count in the PDO:

```
function connect($dbname, $servername) {


        //$dbname is supposed to be retrieved from the if-statement

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "admin";
        $password = "password";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

I've also tried to place the if-statement in the connect(), in case connect() didn't have access to the variable from the if-statement: no success.

I've searched online for info like a madman, but no luck. If you know of a tutorial that covers this stuff, please post it.

Comment: You cannot use `return` in an `if` statement, it is only to return a value from a function. How are you calling your `connect()` function?

Comment: Why are you setting `$servername` in the function when it's an argument?

Comment: Jay: the if-statement was originally a function, ergo the return (but thx for info, wasn't aware of that). The connect() is called from the html file with require_once: 'filename.php'; and with a variable that I created, that refers to connect ($connect = "connect"; and then call it: $connect();) Barman: that's because I used to call the function from the php-file by using those arguments, like this: $connect(name, server); -- I understand there are mistakes, but how would you guys do it? The question is, retrieve the value from the string variable (table name) and add it to the PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved the issue (it's not OO, it's still a bit primitive) was by implementing 3 steps:

1) create a function with if-statements that checks for the radio button value and assigns a value to a variable that corresponds to the table name;

2) create a variable of the function and call it in the PDO (see below);

3) add a simple if-statement inside the PDO function to check if no radio button was clicked.

The first function:

```
function table_name() {
    if (isset($_POST['edify_button'])) {

        if(isset($_POST['p_radio'])) {
            $radio_values = $_POST['p_radio'];
            if ($radio_values == 'p_book') {
                $table_name = 'books';
                return $table_name;

            }elseif ($radio_values == 'p_article') {
                $table_name = 'articles';
                return $table_name;

            }elseif ($radio_values == 'p_journal') {
                $table_name = 'journals';
                return $table_name;
            }
        }else{
                $table_name = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then some variables:

```
$table_name = "table_name";
$function_connect = "connect";
$function_connect(); //initialize the function;
```

And finally the PDO function:

```
function connect() {

        $dbname = 'citation';
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "admin";
        $password = "password";
        $table_name = table_name();


    try {

        //if table is false, connection is refused;
        if (table_name() == false) {
            echo 'Pick a category';
        }else{

        //if table is not false, connection is executed depending on the radio button (which corresponds to a table);

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully" . '<br>'; 

        //$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name //this is where the table is picked
```